# Products disappeared on frontend after magento update

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I updated my Magento to the version 1.9.2.4.
After the successful message, without any errors on Magento Connect, the product widgets carrousel at frontend don't show the products anymore.

Any idea to fix this?

My project URL is: http://104.131.94.62/

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide here the error and what have you done until now to solve it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

try reindexing and cache clear. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer.

Since the update 1.9.2.4, Magento updated it's security on the Widget Blocks. All you need to do is add this permissions at System > Permissions > Blocks.

After the new page loads, you'll see the widget blocks who have Magento permissions to load. To setup a  new widget permission, just click on 'Add New Block'.

On next page, add your block type, like 'ultimo/product_list_featured' (you can get the block type at CMS > Pages). Select 'Allow' and click on save.

Refresh your cache and it's finished.

Thanks for the help.